# Typescript TS2532 - Object is possible undefined

Tags: typescript

```
    <Form.Field>
      <label>Rua</label>
      <input name='endereco.rua' value={user.endereco.rua}  onChange={(e)=>handleInputChange(e)} placeholder='Insira sua Rua' />
      {errors.endereco.rua !== '' && <ErrorMessage>{errors.endereco.rua}</ErrorMessage>}

    </Form.Field>

     <Form.Field>
      <label>Numero</label>
      <input name='endereco.numero' type='number'   onChange={(e)=>handleInputChange(e)} placeholder='Insira seu numero' />
      {errors.endereco.numero !==  undefined  && <ErrorMessage>{errors.endereco.numero}</ErrorMessage>}

    </Form.Field>

  export  interface Errors{
    name?: string;
    password?: string;
    email?: string;
    cpf?: string;
    endereco?: {
        cep?: string;
        cidade?: string;
        bairro?: string;
        rua?: string;
        numero?: string;
    }

   }
```

How can i deactivate this option or solve the issue? It was only now that it gave me this error. Thank you!

error: Typescript TS2532 - Object is possible undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know your specific types, but presumably `errors` or `endereco` could be `undefined`.  You can handle that with something like this:

```
{errors && errors.endereco && <ErrorMessage>{errors.endereco.rua}</ErrorMessage>}
```

If you also want to check that the property itself isn't `undefined`, similar to how you currently do, just add that to the chain:

```
{errors && errors.endereco && errors.endereco.rua && <ErrorMessage>{errors.endereco.rua}</ErrorMessage>}
```

Basically if any value along that chain is `undefined` then it'll short-circuit the `&&` conditions and nothing will be rendered there.  But if all of the values are defined then the `<ErrorMessage/>` element is rendered.

Comment: I have add my interface to the question.

Comment: @HelcioOliveira: Any of those properties can indeed be `undefined` (that's what the `?` in the property name means).  The above code should successfully check for `undefined` values.

Comment: What can i  do? It doesnt need to be undefined at all. I'm new to typescript. I just want to show my message

Comment: @HelcioOliveira: If the properties should never be `undefined` then remove the `?` from the property names.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help!